# Button Corner gets blurred (Android)

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

*I am developing an app for android( Ti Sdk 2.1.2,Android Sdk 2.2). I want rounded corner button but corner get blurred when i apply borderRadius.*

```
var win= Titanium.UI.createWindow();
var login = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Login',
    height :50,
    width : 280,
    top :  50,
    left : 100,
    backgroundImage:'btn_bg.png',
    borderRadius: 5,
    color:'white',

});

win.add(login);

win.open();
```

[btn_bg.png](http://postimage.org/image/pfv5glrbp/)

Comment: once remove the background image and then run again and tell me whats happening then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several Options:

1. if it's a simple color (in your case the image only shows red color) - use the background color instead of an image
2. Use an Android 9-Patch image for the button as described [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens)
3. (bad) use a complete image with rounded and transparent corners as background image.

hint: maybe you should also set border width and border color to avoid blurry appearance.

Comment: using background color it shows corner blurred. Border width and border color will change my app's look . I will look Anroid 9-Patch if it works

Comment: maybe you can provide a screenshot of what you exactly mean with 'blurred'